# How to filter out databases that contains entries to a specific table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

There is a server with a bunch of different databases. Each database has a specific table, lets say  "private.tablename". I need to find a way to go trough all of databases and check if that particular table is empty or not, **if NOT empty**, then list me names of those databases... Going trough 500+ databases manually would be pain in the ***. Also I wouldn't mind listing results from that table as well, I could filter those out later cuz usually those tables contain max 5 rows.

Comment: Write a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in PL/pgSQL - SQL Procedural Language and loop through all databases with dblink:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_databases(
    OUT databasename text,
    OUT numberofrows bigint
) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD; 
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false AND NOT datname = 'postgres' ORDER BY datname) LOOP  
        
        RAISE NOTICE 'Databasename: %', rec.datname;
    
        SELECT tablelist.numberofusers INTO numberofrows FROM dblink('dbname=' || rec.datname || ' port=5432 host=localhost user=admin password=****',
                                               'SELECT count(id) FROM myTable;') AS tablelist(numberofusers bigint);
                RAISE NOTICE 'Databasename: %', numberofrows;
                databasename = rec.datname;             
                RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```